# How to compile a static version of unison

Tags: makefile, ocaml, static-linking, unison

On my OS X box, `brew install unison` gives me version 2.51.2. But the system I need to sync with runs CentOS 6.10 for which there appears to be no existing 2.51.2 binary. I also can't compile from source on that machine as it doesn't have the right tools and I am not root.

To solve this I would like to compile [unison](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison/releases) from source on my Ubuntu machine on which I am root. But this has to be a static compilation to run on the CentOS machine.

> How can I make a static binary of unison?

The [Makefile](https://bpaste.net/show/88611d402af4) has the line `include src/Makefile.OCaml` but I don't know anything about OCaml and am not sure what I would need to change to make a static binary.

Answer (score 2):

In the Makefile, there should be a line `STATIC = false`. Either change that to `true`, or just compile with the line `make STATIC=true`.

Some caution, according to [this blog post](https://carlo-hamalainen.net/2011/07/29/how-to-build-a-static-unison-binary/) the `STATIC` option doesn't actully do anything as of at least version 2.32.52, and I see no changes in the [change log](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/beta/unison-manual.html#sec65) to indicate that this has been fixed, but the author of the blog post says, and I've confirmed, that building a static binary works for the [latest version of Unison, 2.48](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison).